# Permission denied but group has been added

Tags: shell-script, permissions

I'm writing bash script. When I add user there is permission denied communicate but user has been created. How to remove this error from bash?

```
function create() {
  echo "name of group:"
  read turtles
  if [[ -n $turtles ]] && id $turtles > /etc/group 2>&1; then
    echo "This group has already exists"
    sleep $delay_time && exit
  else
    sudo groupadd $turtles && echo "Group has been added"
    sleep $delay_time
  fi
}
```

and message in terminal is:

```
./myname: line 78: /etc/group Permission denied
Group has been added
```

Please help me with this error

Comment: You missing a `]]` somewhere in there. Also, the error comes from the redirection into `/etc/group`.  It is unclear what you intend to do there. And `2>1&1` looks odd. It would be beneficial for you question to describe what you want to do.

Comment: I have this missing ]] and fixed 2>&1 correct in my bash but here I made mistakes. Sorry. I edited post.  `/etc/group` by this I want to check is group exists

Comment: If you add a user to a group, the user should normally log in again for the changes to take effect.

Comment: You don't have a line 78. Please run and show a minimal scrip that has the error.

Comment: My line 78 is: `if [[ -n $turtles ]] && id $turtles > /etc/group 2>&1; then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupadd` man page says:

```
Exit Values
The groupadd command exits with the following values:

0 success
2 invalid command syntax
3 invalid argument to option
4 GID not unique (when -o not used)
9 group name not unique
10 can't update group file
```

> If a group name exists already, it returns 9 (groupadd: group 'name'
>   already exists)

So, your script becomes

```
function create() {
    echo "name of group:"
    read turtles
    sudo groupadd "$turtles" && echo "group $turtles created successfully..."
    sleep $delay_time
}
```

Comment: It's working, thank you. But I would like to check is group already exists so now I have to use `if` like in my code above?

Comment: it will check by default. try with an existing group name and you will see.

Comment: Yes i see, thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0):

## First problem `> /etc/group`:

- You should not be writing to `/etc/group` directly, use addgroup.
- You should not use `>`, it will truncate the file.

## if else

This will to the `else` clause, if there is on error in the predicate. e.g. failing to open the file in the re-direct, will cause the else branch to run.

## `sleep $delay_time && exit`

- no need to sleep.
- no need to exit, it will just skip to `fi`
- use of `&&` if `sleep` fails, then `exit` will not run.

## `turtles`

- Literate programming: Variable name does not make code clear.

## name of group:

- Literate programming: not a clear question to the user.